# My dropdown menu is overhanging the width of my site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My dropdown menu is overhanging width of my site. I want to set an overall site width but my menu is not following this rule. It is overhanging the container width of my site and I can't work out how to just have it open within the container. My URL is https://asnonline.co.nz/ and the problem is occurring with my "all categories" Menu. I've posted an image of the issue below

[image]

Comment: Is this your theme or do you know how to make a child theme? Or do you expect to fix it from the theme's built in settings?

Comment: I'm using flatsome as my theme. And the site is built on a child theme. So I'm looking to use the settings or code to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This particular theme you're running (Flatsome) has the ability to create multi column menus in order to avoid multi levels of sub menus in a single column. I assume the issue you're talking about is also the one that's happening in your Shop by Brand menu item?

https://docs.uxthemes.com/article/51-menu-dropdown

This is because your theme has what is called the UberMenu automatically integrated within it, which is what your theme appears to be using to create your navigation menu, making it stretch into multiple columns instead of a single one, like would be "normal".

To disable the UberMenu, you will need to consult Flatsome's documentation, but I'd suggest looking for a setting somewhere along the lines of Flatsome > Advanced > Integrations > UberMenu from within your Admin Dashboard. Based on UberMenu's documentation, there should be several instances to modify the menu settings, including column widths.

https://sevenspark.com/docs/ubermenu-3/theme-integration/flatsome

Comment: Hey Amanda, I'm not using the uber menu integration and do not have uber menu installed on my site. So the option to disable it is not present. I'm using the stock flatsome Drop down system. The menu I'm talking about is the all categories menu. I'm looking to just have this menu open within the main content are of my site and not outside of it.